# Magento. New Security Patch (SUPEE-7405)

Tags: magento, patch

It can be to allow the patches to be installed automatically, instead of manually?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. However, I feel you should refer this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : no they can't be installed automatically.

Long answer : they are not installed automatically for a good reason. Some sites have specific modifications or specific modules that might break the site if the update was applied. Nearly each of these security patches must be applied with precaution and some decent testing before being ready to be pushed onto production environment.

Comment: Heh, those who wish for automatic patch installation should have had that happen with the original test release of SUPEE-6788 that caused the delay of the RTM release. Most third party modules would just crash the installation. It would have been as good as the one or two Microsoft Windows security patches that would throw a cross section of computers into closed loop reboot.